# Gmail API: Cannot create filters via Google APIs Explorer

Tags: gmail, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to create filters via the Gmail API
Services > Gmail API v1 > gmail.users.settings.filters.create

Listing and lookup of single filters are working but I am not able to create new filters.

Request

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/settings/filters?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "criteria": {
  "query": "test"
 },
 "action": {
  "addLabelIds": [
   "Label_582"
  ]
 }
}
```

Response

```
500

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

"Label_582" is valid.

Any ideas?
Thanks and best regards

Comment: Regardless of whether or not your request is correct, a 5xx error is a server error, not a request error. As such, this is technically something the server maintainers need to correct, not you. That said, it is possible there is something wrong with your request that fixing would work around the server error, so this is still a valid question to ask.

Comment: Thanks @John! Do you know if this is only an issue when using the Google API Explorer or will this occur when using the API from our application as well? (Wanted to test all use cases on the Explorer first before implementation..)

Comment: The APIs Explorer should be making the requests the exact same way you are making them. So I would expect the same issue when you make them yourself.

Comment: Do you have any idea what we can do instead of waiting for "better times"? ;) We have to create Gmail filters from our own build CRM automatically and I cannot believe that we are the only one doing (currently not doing) this. Thank you again!